# how to extract text which matches particular fields in text file using linux commands

Tags: linux, sed, awk

Hi below is my text file

```
{"Author":"john"
  "subject":"java"
  "title":"java cook book.pdf"}

{"title":"Php book.pdf"
 "Author":"Smith"
 "subject":"PHP"}

{"Author":"Smith"
"title":"Java book.pdf"}
```

from the above data i want to extract all titles which contains "java" word, i should get the following output

```
java cook book.pdf
Java book.pdf
```

Please suggest me

Thanks

Comment: Do you know what JSON is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### GNU [sed](/questions/tagged/sed)

```
sed -r '/title.*java/I!d;s/.*:.(.*).}$/\1/' file
```

```
java cook book.pdf
Java book.pdf
```

Answer (score 3):

I will avoid any complex solution and will rely on old good grep+awk+tr instead:

```
$ grep '"title":' test.txt | grep '[Jj]ava' | awk -F: '{print $2}' | tr -d [\"}]
java cook book.pdf
Java book.pdf
```

which works as follow:

1. extract all lines which contain `"title":`
2. extract from these lines all which contain either `Java` or `java`
3. split these lines by `:` and show second field
4. remove `"` and `}` signs

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this with `awk`:

```
awk -F: '$1~/title/&&tolower($2)~/java/{gsub(/\"/,"",$2);print $2}' file
```

#### Explaination:

- `-F:` sets the field separator to `:`
- `$1~/title` checks where first column is `title`
- `tolower($2)~/java/` checks for second column `java` case insensitively
- `gsub(..)` is to remove `"`.
- `print $2` to print your second column

Comment: Thanks for the reply can u please explain me the command so that i can try for other files

Comment: @user2353439 Added the explaination.

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely use a json parser to get flawless results.. I like the one provided with PHP and if your file is, as shown, a bunch json blocks separated with blank lines:

```
foreach( explode("\n\n", file_get_contents('/your/file.json_blocks')) as $js_block ):
    $json = json_decode( trim($js_block) );
    if ( isset( $json['title'] ) && $json['title'] && stripos($json['title'], 'java') ):
        echo trim($json['title']), PHP_EOL;
    endif;
endforeach;
```

This will be a lot more sure fire than doing the same with any given combination of sed/awk/grep/ et al, simply because json is follows a specific format and *should* be used with a parser. As an example, a simple new line in the 'title' which has no real meaning to the json but will break the solution provided by Jaypal.. Please see this for a similar problem: parsing xhtml with regex and why you shouldn't do it: [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)