# How can I use the version from my build.gradle file in my bitbucket-pipelines.yml file

Tags: bitbucket-pipelines

Currently when I change the version number in my project I have to define it in my build.gradle file and several places in my bitbucket-pipelines.yml.  This is because I have scripts to upload files to my project's Downloads folder.  Is there a way to get the version from the build.gradle file?  I would like to just update one file when I increment the version.

build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

def buildNumber = project.properties['buildNumber'] ?:'0'
group 'edu.csusb.iset'
version "2020.1-BETA"

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes('Main-Class': 'edu.csusb.iset.projectname.Main',
            'Implementation-Title': 'ProjectName',
            'Implementation-Version': "$version, build $buildNumber")
    }

    from {
        configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it)         }
    }
}

task packSrc(type: Tar) {
    archiveAppendix.set("src")
    archiveVersion.set("$project.version")
    archiveExtension.set("tar.gz")
    destinationDirectory = file("$buildDir/dist")
    compression = Compression.GZIP

    from 'build.gradle'
    from 'settings.gradle'
    from('src') {
        include '**/*'
        into "src"
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    ...
}
```

bitbucket-pipelines.yml

```
image: openjdk:11
pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        name: Gradle build
        caches:
          - gradle
        script:
          - bash ./gradlew build
    - step:
        name: Deploy downloads
        trigger: manual
        caches:
          - gradle
        script:
          - bash ./gradlew build
          - pipe: atlassian/bitbucket-upload-file:0.1.6
            variables:
              BITBUCKET_USERNAME: $BITBUCKET_USERNAME
              BITBUCKET_APP_PASSWORD: $BITBUCKET_APP_PASSWORD
              FILENAME: build/libs/ProjectName-2020.1-BETA.jar
          - bash ./gradlew packSrc
          - pipe: atlassian/bitbucket-upload-file:0.1.6
            variables:
              BITBUCKET_USERNAME: $BITBUCKET_USERNAME
              BITBUCKET_APP_PASSWORD: $BITBUCKET_APP_PASSWORD
              FILENAME: build/dist/ProjectName-src-2020.1-BETA.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 1):

Bitbucket Pipelines is just running bash/shell commands on a Unix docker machine. So you can use the normal unix shell commands, like [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) or [perl](/questions/tagged/perl), to extract text from a text file:

#### Use `awk`

**build.gradle** contains a line:

```
version "2020.1-BETA"
```

```bash
awk '/^version/{gsub(/\"/,"",$2);print $2}' build.gradle
Output: 2020.1-BETA
```

#### Explanation:

- `awk` = extract text on a line, using the default space character `" "` as a delimiter
- `^` = Regular expression to start at the beginning of a line only
- `version` = Look for the word "version", case-sensitive
- `{gsub(/\"/,"",$2);print $2}` = strip out all speech mark characters `"`, and print column 2
- More info and source: [how to extract text which matches particular fields in text file using linux commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17086628/how-to-extract-text-which-matches-particular-fields-in-text-file-using-linux-com)

#### Another way with `perl`

**build.gradle** contains a line:

```
version "2020.1-BETA"
```

```sh
perl -nle 'print $& while m{(?<=version ").*?(?=")}g' build.gradle
Output: 2020.1-BETA
```

#### Explanation:

- Extract the text between two words of: `version "` and `"`, using a regular expression
- `perl -nle` = extract text from a line in a file, using regular expressions
- `(?<=version ")` = Look for the start tag of `version "`, using negative lookahead `?<=` to make the capture start at the end of the tag
- `.*?` = Capture any string, after the first tag. Use `?` to make the match 'non-greedy', which means it will stop at the first match, to match as few characters as possible. See: [Regular expression to stop at first match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2503413/regular-expression-to-stop-at-first-match#2503438)
- `(?=")` = Look for the end tag of a speech mark `"`, using positive lookahead `?=` to make the capture stop before the tag
- `g` = global search on all lines of a multi-line file
- More info and sources: [grep -P no longer works. How can I rewrite my searches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16658333/grep-p-no-longer-works-how-can-i-rewrite-my-searches)  and  [How to use sed/grep to extract text between two words?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13242469/how-to-use-sed-grep-to-extract-text-between-two-words)

#### Use the shell commands in the yml script

You can therefore use either `awk` or `perl` in your yml script. Capture the output as an environment variable called `$APP_VERSION`, and reuse this environment variable:

```yaml
script:
  - bash ./gradlew build
  # Extract the version string from build.gradle into an environment variable
  - export APP_VERSION=$(awk '/^version/{gsub(/\"/,"",$2);print $2}' build.gradle)
  - echo $APP_VERSION # debug to print the extracted text of "2020.1-BETA"
  - pipe: atlassian/bitbucket-upload-file:0.1.6
    variables:
      BITBUCKET_USERNAME: $BITBUCKET_USERNAME
      BITBUCKET_APP_PASSWORD: $BITBUCKET_APP_PASSWORD
      FILENAME: "build/libs/ProjectName-$APP_VERSION.jar" # Use the extracted text here
```

**Alternative way:**

```bash
script:
  - bash ./gradlew build
  # Extract the version string from build.gradle into an environment variable
  - export APP_VERSION=$( perl -nle 'print $& while m{(?<=version ").*?(?=")}g' build.gradle )
  - echo $APP_VERSION # debug to print the extracted text of "2020.1-BETA"
  - pipe: atlassian/bitbucket-upload-file:0.1.6
    variables:
      BITBUCKET_USERNAME: $BITBUCKET_USERNAME
      BITBUCKET_APP_PASSWORD: $BITBUCKET_APP_PASSWORD
      FILENAME: "build/libs/ProjectName-${APP_VERSION}.jar" # Use the extracted text here
```